# Convert char* to <string>

Tags: c++, string, vector

This is my first post, so please be understanding for me :)

I would like to use vector of strings to make sort data easy, but I need this string also to function fun1. So I would like to **convert char* word to string str** but i can't manage to do it. I was searching answer for my question but I didn't find.
Please help, here is code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

vector <string> tab;
vector <string> tab2;
int l['Z'+1];

void fun1(char *t)
{
    for(int i = 0; t[i]; i++)
        l[t[i]]++;
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
        if(l[i])
        {
            t[j++] = i;
            l[i--]--;
        }
}

int main()
{
    char * word;
    string str;
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    int z;
    int n;
    cin >> z;
    while(z--)
    {
        cin >> n;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> word;
            fun1(word);
            str.assign(word, sizeof(word));
            tab.push_back(str);
        }
        sort(tab.begin(), tab.end());
        for(int i = 0; i < tab.size(); i++)
            cout << tab[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: `cin >> word;` operates on an uninitialized pointer and there's never memory allocated.

Comment: Also `sizeof(word)` gives the size of the `word` variable in bytes (= size of pointer), not the number of characters in the char array it points to. To do that, use `strlen`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I have no idea, why you want to convert char* to string. In your solution firstly you have to allocate memory for chars

```
char *word = new char[HOW_MANY_CHARS]
```

But there is better solution. You can write:

```
cin >> str;
fun1(str);
tab.push_back(str);
```

And you have to change fun1 to:

```
void fun1(string &t);
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot :) I must read more about strings, because I don't know the class and I didn't know I can change string by the reference. I thought string is a const char.